# I am currently drawing a flag with python turtle module and want to fill in specific parts of the flag with color. How can I acheive this?

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

This is my first project with the turtle module and I am drawing a flag, and although I am finished I'm still wondering how I can fill in specific parts of the flag with color.

```
t.color('red', 'green')
t.begin_fill()
```

I tried using the t.color function but it comes out really funky

Comment: See [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), [how to ask good questions](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) and [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You should show us the code you wrote to draw a flag and your attempt to fill specific parts of the flag with color. Or otherwise show us that you have made an effort to solve this yourself by referring to relevant documentation.

Comment: You also say you "tried using the t.color function but it comes out really funky". Show us the code you wrote, an example of the output, and explain what is "funky" about the output.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
t.fillcolor('red')
t.begin_fill()

//your code here
t.end_fill()
```